# React Hook doesn't update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks

React and JS in general are new to me, so I'm still kinda bad at this. What I understand the least in this whole situation are React Hooks and the problem with them not updating sometimes. I know things like why and how you have to avoid multiple calls of a setter and stuff like that, but this particular issue is hard for me to understand or even google correctly. Either I find class-based this.state stuff or unanswered questions here.

How to make the hook update, when I need it. For example, this is `Autocomplete` component from Material-UI. when I select an option in it I want to put its value into newFKSchema const in `getTables` to work with it. Only first three lines in this method are important for this question. But `console.log` shows that `newFKSchema` is empty. And if I choose another option, newFKSchema will have the previous option in it. So there is like a one-turn delay. I don't understand why exactly is that happening and how to make it work like I want. Sorry for messy code, I've already made some attempts to make it work.

If it is not hard for you, after providing a solution please explain it a little.

```
  const allSchemas = [
    '',
    'ADDITIONAL',
    'BOOKKEEPING',
    'CB',
    'DEPOSIT',
    'DOGORG',
    'GENERALUSE',
    'NSI',
    'PAYMENTS',
    'PLASTIC',
    'SAFECELL',
    'SWIFT',
    'TARIFF',
  ];
  const [newFKSchema, setNewFKSchema] = React.useState(allSchemas[0]);

  const getTables = (schema) => {
    var newSchema = schema;
    setNewFKSchema(newSchema);
    console.log(newFKSchema);

    if (newFKSchema !== '') {
      superagent
      .get('/api/tech')
      .query({schema: schema})
      .then((response) =>{
        if (response.status === 200) {
          const newTables = [];
          response.body.forEach(e => {newTables.push(e)});
          setAllTables(newTables);
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        if (error.response.statusCode === 400) {
            alert("No tables were found!");
        }
      }); 
    }
  }

  <FormControl fullWidth>
    <Autocomplete
      id="autocomplete-schema"
      options={allSchemas.slice(1)}
      value={newFKSchema}
      onChange={(event, value) => {setNewFKSchemaError(false); getTables(value)}} //setNewFKSchema(value); 
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Schema name" variant="outlined" fullWidth />} />
    <FormHelperText className={classes.formHelper}>
      {newFKSchemaError ? "Needs input!" : ''} 
    </FormHelperText>
  </FormControl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use place `getTables` in `useEffect` with `newFKSchema` as a dependency

**Example**

```js
const allSchemas = [
    '',
    'ADDITIONAL',
    'BOOKKEEPING',
    'CB',
    'DEPOSIT',
    'DOGORG',
    'GENERALUSE',
    'NSI',
    'PAYMENTS',
    'PLASTIC',
    'SAFECELL',
    'SWIFT',
    'TARIFF',
  ];

const { FormControl, FormHelperText, TextField } = window.MaterialUI;

const { Autocomplete } = window.MaterialUILab;

const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const renderInput = (params) => <TextField {...params} label="Schema name" variant="outlined" fullWidth />

const getTables = (schema) => Promise.resolve([1,2,3])

const App = () => {
  const [{error, schemas, schema}, setData] = useState({
  error: false,
  schemas: [],
  schema: null,
  });
  const [tables, setTables] = useState([]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setData(data => ({
      ...data,
      schemas: allSchemas
    }))
  
  }, []);
  
   useEffect(() => {
   console.log(schema);
    if(!schema) {
      return () => {};
    }
    
    getTables(schema).then(result => {
    
      setTables(schema);
    
    })
  
  }, [schema]);
  
  const onChange = (event, schema) => {

    setData(data => ({
      ...data,
      schema,
      error: schema ? false : true
    }))
  }

return <FormControl fullWidth>
    <Autocomplete
      id="autocomplete-schema"
      options={schemas}
      value={schema}
      onChange={onChange}
      renderInput={renderInput} />
    <FormHelperText>
      {error ? "Needs input!" : ''} 
    </FormHelperText>
  </FormControl>  
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@latest/umd/material-ui.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/material-ui-lab-umd@4.0.0-alpha.32/material-ui-lab.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: so, somehow putting a hook inside the useEffect is the only way to do that?

Comment: I think so. One advantage of that approach is when you select another option you would also like to cancel current `getTable` request and start another one

Answer (score 1):

Ok so let's walk through what happens here:

you call `getTables(value)` in the `onChange` trigger, with the parameters `event` and `value`.

`value` is set to `newFKSchema`, which you defined as `allSchemas[0]`, which is `''`

then you do this:

```js
const getTables = (schema) => {
    var newSchema = schema;
    setNewFKSchema(newSchema);
    console.log(newFKSchema);
```

We know that schema is `''`. so newSchema will also be `''` and setNewFKSchema will set the schema to `''` as well and obviously console log will also log `''`

So, what did you expect to happen exactly?

Comment: `schema` is not `''`. It gets `value`. And `value` is an option selected in Autocomplete. It is alson not `''`. Read the code again.

Comment: I don't understand who upvotes it. The answer is wrong. `schema` is not `''`. `schema=value` and `value` is what I choose in the `Autocomplete` component, it can't be `''`

Comment: `value` = `''` though, because that's what you defined it as.

Comment: omg, pls read this https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/ or watch this example https://codesandbox.io/s/9v197

`value` changes in `onChange`. I don't understand, why I came here to ask about React hooks, but instead I have to learn people, how JS functions work

Comment: I don't know how I can explain it any more clearly.

I get that you have set an onChange, but the value you pass with onChange is empty. So it does nothing.

Ask a question, and then complain I don't know what I'm doing, really?

The example you linked is NOTHING alike. Their state is dynamic, and updates. Your state is static, and only ever is `''`

Study the examples a bit more before you say my answer is wrong.

In fact, read the answer and try to understand it before you say it's wrong.

Comment: it is not only ever `''` lol. I've already said that if you choose an option first time, for example `ADDITIONAL`, `console.log` will still show `''`, but if you choose something again, for example `BOOKKEEPING` `console.log` will output `ADDITIONAL`. Try to actually run this code before arguing how it works

Comment: The code you shared isn't complete then because there's nothing in the code you have shown that will set the state to anything other than `''`

Answer (score 1):

React [state updates are asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#why-is-setstate-giving-me-the-wrong-value) and you are doing a console.log soon after `setNewFKSchema`, hence you see the previous value.

**Fix**

```js
const getTables = (schema) => {
    var newSchema = schema;
    setNewFKSchema(newSchema);
    console.log(newFKSchema); //<------ don't do this
    console.log(newSchema);//<------ do this

    if (newFKSchema !== '') {
  ...
```

One improvement you can make to your code is to simply do `setnewFKSSchema` upon `onChange` and use a `useEffect` with `newFKSSchema` as dependency. This will basically call your api and do things when you do a select.

**Like this**

```js
...
useEffect(() => {
    // var newSchema = schema;
    //setNewFKSchema(newSchema);
    console.log(newFKSchema); //<---- this will always print latest value

    if (newFKSchema !== '') {
      superagent
      .get('/api/tech')
      .query({schema: schema})
      .then((response) =>{
        if (response.status === 200) {
          const newTables = [];
          response.body.forEach(e => {newTables.push(e)});
          setAllTables(newTables);
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        if (error.response.statusCode === 400) {
            alert("No tables were found!");
        }
      }); 
    }
}, [newFKSSchema])
```

**Autocomplete**

```js
<Autocomplete
      id="autocomplete-schema"
      options={allSchemas.slice(1)}
      value={newFKSchema}
      onChange={(event, value) => {setNewFKSchemaError(false); setNewFKSchema(value)}} 
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Schema name" variant="outlined" fullWidth />} />
```

Comment: Incrorrect answer. The point of the method is not to show something in console. In the next line you can see that I have to check `newFKSchema` value. `If` returns `false` because the `newFKSchema` is still empty while it has to contain value I passed to the `getTable`

The request also has to be made only when I need it, not as soon as the page loads, which useEffect does

Comment: ok, it kinda works, but only because the Autocomplete field doesn't have a default value. It is more a workaround, than a solution

Comment: Autocomplete certainly has `defaultValue` ... https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/

Comment: mhm. It also has this written next to it: "The default input value. Use when the component is not controlled." As you can notice my component is controlled. So I decide what default value would be by setting `newFKSchema`.